# log in with session does not work

Tags: php, sql, session, authentication

I have this script sign in first with sql insert into query and redirected to login page. I checked all my queries on phpmyadmin. All queries are working. I do not have any error message in my query. Also it is suppose to show " password/username does not match" message if there is incorrect user/password. After i submit form, the page did not redirect to welcome page and form field clears. 
 this is my login page

```
 <?php

    require_once "./include/variables.inc.php";

    $debug =0;
    $error_text = "";
    $uname = "";
    $pwd = "";

    session_start();

        if (!isset($_SESSION['member_id'])){
                if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

                    if($debug) {
                        echo "<pre>";
                        print_r($_POST);
                        echo "</pre>";

                        //die("temp stop point");
                    }//end ofdebug if

                $uname = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,trim($_POST['uname']));
                $pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,trim($_POST['pwd']));

                if (!empty($uname) && !empty($pwd)) {

                    $query = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE username = '".$uname."'
AND password = '".MD5($pwd)."'";

                    echo $query;

                    $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query) or die ("Error in query". mysql_error());


                    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

                    $_SESSION['member_id'] = $row['member_id'];
                    $_SESSION['member_name'] = $row['member_name'];

                    header('Location:index.php');

                    }
                     else {

                        $error_text .= "The username/password are incorrect. Please enter correct username and password.";
                        }
                }
            }//end of if(isset($_POST["submit"])

    }

    require_once('./include/html.head.php');
?>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <?php require_once('./include/header.php'); ?>

        <div id="side">
        <?php require_once('./include/pb.side.php'); ?>
        </div>

        <div id="content">
            <div class="form">

                <p class="strong">All Santa helpers log-in here.</p>
                    <?= $error_text ?>

                    <form method="post" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <p>User Name: <input name="uname" type="text" value="<?= $uname ?>"></p>
                        <p>Password: <input name="pwd" type="password"></p>
                        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Login">
                    </form>
            </div>

            <div class="rdeer">
                <img src="images/login_img.png" alt="Rain Deer">
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php require_once('./include/footer.php'); ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and function php is

```
<?php
    function user_authenticated($username, $password) {
        if(!empty($username) && !empty($password)) {
            $query = "SELECT userName, password FROM employees WHERE userName = '".$username."' and password = '".$password."'"; 

            $result= mysqli_query($dbc, $query) 
            or die ("Query does not  work." . mysql_error());

        // If result matched $username and $password, table row must be 1 row
    } else {
    echo "Query error. ";
    }
}
```

Comment: add the following to the begining of your php it will help you to see other php errors:

error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set("display_errors", 1);

Comment: first of all always use a try catch block for these situations to get a readable error message.second,where have you used "user_authenticated"?

Answer (score 0):

Notice the line `mysqli_num_rows($result)`. Replace it with `mysqli_num_rows($result)>0` since that function returns an int.